# In DocBlocks, should I always use a single line notation when writing one line?

Tags: php, docblocks

Let's say I have one line of `summary`, must I right it like that:

```
/** summary */
```

or can I write it like this:

```
/**
 * summary
 */
```

I prefer the second option, but is that required to use the first option?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the proper PHP function documentation format?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904214/what-is-the-proper-php-function-documentation-format)

Comment: @kamil09875 It is really not the same question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/guides/docblocks.html), "DocComments **may be** a single line in size but **may also** span multiple lines" (emphasis mine.)

So, you can do it either way.

Comment: That is true, it says that there is an option for a single line and an option for multiple lines, but it does not specify **When** should I use each of them. Thanks.

Comment: If you have a single line comment, you **may** use one or the other. End of story.